# Is there any login api for nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

In nopcommerce how to create api which will post username and password to system and on return give response true or false, if logged in then true else false

Answer (score 0):

You can send in a json item the password and user name and catch them in a function like:

```
public JsonResult Login(){
    var key = Request.Params[0];
}
```

Then in "key" you will have the username and password. But you should have a read about how to create a login and use bearers tokens to create a secure login page.